# Global "Trigger function on hover" in Angular2

Tags: angular, audio

I'd like to do this:

```
$('button.hoverSoundOne').hover(function() {
    this.configService.playSound('HoverOne');
});

$('button.clickSoundOne').click(function() {
    this.configService.playSound('clickOne');
});
```

But while this is a mere 6 lines in jQuery, it seems to be that in Angular this would take 40+ lines of code, once for every button in my app. I'm not sure how to do this in a... global way, in Angular.

What is the best way to do this in Angular?

---

**Edit**: To clarify my objective, as part of a game, I'm adding sounds to every button in the game. For example, I have

1. Header buttons,
2. Lobby buttons,
3. Game buttons,
4. Powerup buttons,
5. Facebook buttons,
6. etc

Some of these have their own sound effect, but most of them use a generic sound effect.

I could create a new component that looks like this:

```
<audioButton [class]="" [hoverSound]="" [clickSound]="" (click)="">ClickMe</audioButton>
```

but I was hoping there was a better way.

**Edit #2**: Apparently there IS a better way, and they're  **Directive**s! Thanks to **cgTag** for such a beautiful solution.

Comment: Are you trying to achive that in angularJS or angular4+?

Comment: I'm currently working with Angular6.

Comment: You could make a custom component that use a service to handle the function `.hover` and `.click`. In this way you can even have a list of `SoundComponent` that will always use the same service with the same two `Subjects/BehaviorSubjects/Input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different behaviors here. A hover and click behavior on different selectors. So you could create two different directives, or a single directive with an input to control the behavior.

```
$('button.hoverSound').hover(function() {
    this.configService.playSound('Hover');
});

$('button.clickSound').click(function() {
    this.configService.playSound('click');
});
```

The above would be implemented as fellows

```
@Directive({selector:'button.hoverSound'})
export class HoverSoundDirective {
     public constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
     @HostListener('mouseover')
     public mouseOver() {
         this.configService.playSound('Hover');
     }
}

@Directive({selector:'button.clickSound'})
export class HoverSoundDirective {
     public constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
     @HostListener('click')
     public click() {
         this.configService.playSound('Click');
     }
}
```

As you can see, if you take a *jQuery* approach to front-end programming the resulting source code is longer and more time consuming to maintain.

It is better to throw away what you've done with jQuery and start over with Angular/React/Vue and approach problems from a web component design.

**UPDATED:**

You can use input parameters to configure how a directive will work. I recommend that you read the Tour of Heros tutorial on the Angular website. Which covers the topic of creating web components.

https://angular.io/tutorial

Create a generic playable directive:

```
@Directive({selector:'button[playable]'})
export class PlayableDirective {

     public constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

     @Input('playable') playable: string;

     @Input() hover: boolean = false;

     @HostListener('mouseover')
     public mouseOver() {
         if(this.hover) {
             this.configService.playSound(this.playable);
         }
     }

     @HostListener('click')
     public click() {
         if(!this.hover) {
             this.configService.playSound(this.playable);
         }
     }
}
```

The above creates a directive that will play a sound when a button is clicked. The HTML markup would look like this.

```
 <button playable="Powerups">Click Me</button>
```

You can add a parameter to use the hover state to play the sound

```
 <button playable="Powerups" [hover]="true">Click Me</button>
```

What inputs and logic you use inside the directive is up to you.

Comment: I REALLY like these directives, and it appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. But... you don't like it, so what is the correct angular approach? To create a new component that looks like this: <audioButton [class]="" [hoverSound]="" [clickSound]="" (click)="">ClickMe</audioButton> ?

Comment: @EliezerBerlin I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to answer that question. I would say that the component would simply look like this in the HTML `<audioButton>ClickMe</audioButton>`. The behavior of what happens when you click it would be inside the component. Components have a template and directives don't. Directives are closer to your jQuery approach but are not web components.

Comment: I have... a **lot** of buttons. I've edited my original question to better reflect the scope of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin I've updated my answer to expand on how to configure a directive, but this is turning into a tutorial which is off topic for this website. You should give this a try, and if you have more questions come back and ask another question. You get more rep points and so do other people.

Comment: Your update was **exactly** what I needed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is the final version of my code, and it works wonderfully.

```
// 1: (Real Use case):
// <button appSoundClick="aaaa.mp3" appSoundHover="bbbb.mp3"></button>

// 2: (Does nothing because the button is disabled):
// <button appSoundHover="aaaa.mp3" disabled="true"></button>

// 3: (uses default sound bbbb.mp3 on click):
// <div appSoundClick></div>


@Directive({
  selector: '[appSoundHover]'
})
export class SoundHoverDirective {
  @Input() appSoundHover: string;

  public constructor(private configService: ConfigurationService) {}

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  public mouseenter() {
    if (!this.appSoundHover) {
      this.appSoundHover = 'bbbb.mp3';
    }
    this.configService.playSound(this.appSoundHover);
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSoundClick]'
})
export class SoundClickDirective {
  @Input() appSoundClick: string;

  public constructor(private configService: ConfigurationService) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  public click() {
    if (!this.appSoundClick) {
      this.appSoundClick = 'bbbb.mp3';
    }
    this.configService.playSound(this.appSoundClick);
  }

}
```